# What can cause libs to not be found on raspberry pi

Tags: software-compilation, gcc

On my Raspberry Pi, with Debian Squeeze, I want to link to the shared objects in `/opt/vc/lib`. I have added this directory to a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` which is included in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. The compiler/linker runs without error, but upon execution, the program complains about missing .so files. Running `ldd` confirms that the libs cannot be found, but running `ldconfig -v`, after running `ldconfig`, shows the libs are in the cache.

What can cause this problem?

EDIT

Another thing that could cause this issue is an RPATH set in the executable - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath).

Comment: Did you run `sudo ldconfig`? Are the libs/dir listed in output from `ldconfig -v`? The linker and loader are two different things (ldd vs ld).

Comment: Yes I have checked both of these things.

Comment: What exactly is the message about .so files?

Comment: Are you actually passing the correct linker flags to gcc?

Comment: Are you trying to access the share object using **dlopen** ? In that case, the presence of the **.so** file will not be checked at compile time. Please post the complete compilation command that you are running.

Comment: This problem was with an old raspbian version, and so probably isn't relevant anymore. How should I answer the question? Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending your path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable and re-compiling. The only other thing i know would be to create links to your libraries in one of the standard library locations.

Comment: I have actually already tried both of these things already, without success.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as I've reformatted my pi since this question was asked, and it has useful information in it

Answer (score 2):

to make linking work you'll need to run ldconfig

$ sudo ldconfig

(oh well already in comments above. didn't see that until post)